# why is @SuppressLint("WrongCall") required only after method extraction

Tags: android, suppress-warnings, measure, onmeasure

I have this andorid code:

```
      @Override
      protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
       //some code
          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
   ..
      }
```

no errors.

but when I extract the last lines into a private method I get this warning which requires to add a suppression annotation to the private method.

specious method call, should probably call `measure`

```
      @Override
      protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
       ...
        foo(textMaxWidth);
      }

      private void foo(int textMaxWidth) {
...
          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
   ..
      }
```

why is the suppression needed only after extraction?

@SuppressLint("WrongCall")

Answer (score 0):

Because usually you only call super methods from their overrides, not from separate methods. And if you do call them from separate methods, you might not be overriding them (so `super.whatever()` is the same as `whatever()`);

Your IDE is warning you of this in case you accidentally copied some code over and included that call by accident.

In your example code at least, I don't really see a reason to do the super call in a separate method though. If you need to contents of `foo()` to be called before the super method, just put it after you invoke `foo()`.

Comment: thanks, but why does the super.onMeasure() has to be in the overriden method?super call my parent instance either way. no? what did you mean `super.whatever() is the same as whatever()` it does but i call `super` in foo as well

Comment: It doesn't have to be. IDE warnings are just warnings. And I meant that `super.whatever()` and `whatever()` are equivalent if you don't override `whatever()`.

Comment: can you explain? if i call `super.foo()` and override `foo()`. it won't call my parent's `foo()`? and if i call `super.foo()` and won't override `foo()`. it won't call my parent's `foo()`?

Comment: @EladBenda no, I said *if you aren't overriding the method*

Comment: yes, but i still don't understand what would be the different execution path of calling super.onMeasure() when you override or when you *don't* override `onMeasure`?

Comment: @EladBenda super calls the method in the class you extend. No super calls your override method, if it exists.